# Test all links for validity on a page using Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, end-to-end

What I am trying to achieve in Protractor is getting all the links on a page and go to them one by one to check if there is a link that routes to a 404 page.

The following piece of code comes from my email page object, please note that I am calling `replace` on the href because the links on the pages that I will test are the following format: `https://app.perflectie.nl/something` and I want to end-to-end test on `https://staging.perflectie.nl` and on my localhost.

```
// Used to check for 'broken' links - links that lead to a 404 page
Email.prototype.verifyLinkQuality = function() {
    browser.driver.findElements(by.css('a')).then(function (elements) {

        elements.forEach(function(el) {
            // Change the url to the base url this tests now runs on, e.g. localhost or staging
            el.getAttribute('href').then(function(href) {
                var url = href.replace(/https\:\/\/app\.perflectie\.nl\//g, localhost);

                browser.get(url);

                browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
                    expect(url).not.toContain('/Error/');
                    browser.navigate().back();
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

If I run this, I am getting the following error message:

```
Failed: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-QLFLPK5', ip: '169.254.82.243', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_73'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

I am at a loss why this is failing, and I would very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of going back and forth, which often *leads to stale element reference errors* cause of the DOM change/reload, I would collect all the links into an array using [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) and then process them one by one. This would also have a *positive impact on the performance of the test*:

```
$$('a').map(function(link) {
    return link.getAttribute("href").then(function (href) {
        return href.replace(/https\:\/\/app\.perflectie\.nl\//g, localhost);
    });
}).then(function(links) {
    links.forEach(function(link) {
        browser.get(link);
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).not.toContain('/Error/');
    });
});
```

Note that there is also no need to resolve the `.getCurrentUrl()` explicitly since `expect()` would do that implicitly for us before making the expectation.

Comment: Thank you @alecxe! Great that you also took performance into consideration. Really appreciate it.